# More than one tasklet in a step?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, tasklet

I have a tasklet setting some information into my JobContext, and another one checking some stuff to know if I can execute the next steps in my batch or not.
Both tasklets work well if I use two different steps in my job flow, but I'd like to use these two tasklets in the same step.

I tried to add twice ".tasklet(taskletName)" in my batch configuration like this :

```
return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepSettings").tasklet(taskletSettings).tasklet(taskletChecking).listener(executionContextListener).listener(stepExecutionListener).build();
```

It doesn't work: only one of the tasklets is executed (it seems to be the second one). I didn't see anything in spring doc ; is there a way to do this ? Or doesn't Spring allow to have more than one tasklet in the same step ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only one tasklet for step (I think this is by design).
If you need pre-conditions check to flow your job use a [`JobExecutionDecider`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/job/flow/JobExecutionDecider.html).